# Reachability Test for cellular Data

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, reachability

I am currently using the class below to check for internet connection but it does not return true when the user have cellular data connection

```
    import Foundation
   import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags == .reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .connectionRequired

        return isReachable && !needsConnection

    }
}
```

I need to change this so that it could return true for cellular as well, I have seen people use Reachability class from git but I have use this through my app so I need to change this class but I don't know how could I do that

and the usage is like below :`

```
 if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
    print("Internet connection OK")

 JSONParseFunction()

} else {
        print("Internet connection FAILED")
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "You are not connected to internet ", message: "make sure you are connected to internet ", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "چشم")
        alert.show()
    }
    `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3:**
The Code provided by you only works in case wifi is available it will not work in case of cellular data.

Just change your below mentioned lines of code i.e.

```
// Only Working for WIFI

let isReachable = flags == .reachable
let needsConnection = flags == .connectionRequired
return isReachable && !needsConnection
```

with below mentioned code i.e.

```
// Working for both WIFI and Cellular

//kSCNetworkFlagsReachable: The specified node name or address can be reached using the current network configuration.

let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
let retVal = (isReachable && !needsConnection)
return retVal
```

Comment: Thanks sooner than your post I have used Reachability class from Git by the way this is easier I would use it in future projects

Comment: Welcome. BTW Reachability is also a good one. I personally used it in my different projects.